# Adding a PHP expression warning exception in CSS validator

Tags: aptana3

I am working with php variables in CSS files. I cannot figure out how to add a warning exception to the CSS validator for <\?php echo $purple; ?>

I tried .*<\?php.*\?> and .*\<\?php.*\?>. But the error keeps poping out at < as *Syntax Error: unexpected token "<"*

Answer (score 0):

I believe when you add CSS Validator exceptions, you make a regular expression for the error or warning text, not the cause of it. E.g., don't add an exception for `.*<\?php.*\?>`, add it for `Syntax Error: unexpected token "<"`. See this page for examples: http://morganizeit.com/2008/04/configure-aptana-to-ignore-css-hacks/

It is also worth pointing out that if your regular expression doesn't seem to have an effect on the error/warning you are working on, you may be adding it to the wrong validator as there are often multiple ones at work in any given editor. For example, when I edit CSS, I sometimes get warnings from the CSS Syntax Validator and I sometimes get errors from the W3C Stylesheet Validator. So if your expression is not working in one of those, try it on the other. You can determine an error's source by disabling a validator temporarily and seeing if the warning/error quits.

Comment: Tried some variants of .\*Syntax Error: unexpected token "<".\*, but its still a no go. But I confirmed it once more, the error comes from CSS validation (when validating on build - logically)

Comment: I only encountered issues with this functionality when I tried to use the `"<"` character combination. If I replace the `<` with `*`, it works. I suspect there is either a regex character you can use here, or the error message is not using a true `<` but an HTML entity or Unicode combination. If you find a way to use the `<` character in your filter, I think people would find it useful. Unfortunately, I could not find this info easily.